# Exporting to a text file with fixed format using VB.Net MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I know it's possible to write to a text file but my question is can I export data from a datagridview into a text file and have it be displayed in the text file with a format? I've seen tutorials on how to export onto Microsoft Excel but I don't know how to do it on a text file on a fixed format.

For example it would look like this:

```
Report # 1 Alpha/all employee


                             MEAL SYSTEM FOR EMPLOYEES

                                 MEAL TALLY
                     For the Month of ____________, ______
                                        (Month)     (Year)

Employee No. : 
Employee Name : Lastname, Firstname MI.

     Date        Time         Meal Period


  05/21/2014   12:34:29       Lunch  (11:00 am - 12:00 nn)



Total No. of Meal(s) : 21
```

Is it even possible to make it look like this? I'll just be getting data from the datagridview

Comment: I dont think you have done enough research, writing data to a text file is one of the most common operations. From a DataTable (or the DataGridViews source) all you would need to do is iterate over all the columns and rows and throw in some Tabs to format it. What research have you done so far?

Comment: I actually done research about that after I posted this, but I still don't have any idea how to do it. I am not that good in programming sorry. What I have researched is it will only output the data line by line based on the rows of the datagridview. But that's not what I need because I will be basing on data from 2 tables and I really don't have any idea how to do it and it is depressing.